# Moving elements left and right in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, element

I'm trying to get an element to move in a random X and Y direction every second and every direction should be different for each element when a check box is clicked.

The code I have so far is....

```
 <div id="exam" class="exam">
            Exam 1
            <input type="button" id="copy" value="Make Copy" onclick="makeCopy()" />
            <input type="button" id="array" value="Get Array" onclick="makeArray()" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="moving" onclick="doMove()">Making Them Move!!
    </div>

   <script>
     function doMove() {
            moving.style.left = (moving.style.left+10)+'px';
            setTimeout(doMove,1);
        }
   </script>
```

This isn't working for me...Does anyone know how I can improve the function to make them move like I stated above?

This is the code I have now....

```
    <div id="exam" class="exam">
            Exam 1
            <input type="button" id="copy" value="Make Copy" onclick="makeCopy()" />
            <input type="button" id="array" value="Get Array" onclick="makeArray()" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="moving" onclick="doMove()">Making Them Move!!
        </div>
<script>
            function doMove() {
                var moving = document.getElementById("moving");
                moving.style.left = (moving.style.left+10)+'px';
            }
            setTimeout(doMove,1000);
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For actually working the element must have position absolute and left =0 or something if you want to change left with js. Use css like this

```
  <p id="moving" style="position: absolute;left: 500px;">hi</p>
```

This should be like this

```
<script>
 function doMove() {
      var moving=  document.getElementById("moving");
      var leftpx = parseInt(moving.style.left);
       moving.style.left = leftpx + 10 + 'px';
       }

 setInterval(doMove,1000);//1000 means 1 sec

</script>
```

Comment: See this stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988214/moving-a-div-left-and-right-continously

Comment: I'm still not getting any movement :/

Comment: I even tried what you edited and it still didn't work.

Comment: See the element is a check box that is supposed to move each element already made in different directions.

Comment: I think we're trying to do two different things lol...... I'm trying to get an existing element to move in an X and Y direction when a check box is selected. If there is more than one element then one element will go to the left and one will go to the right

Comment: The above function tries to move an element. Put your own logic to play with your situation. I posted here to move an element from its current position. You can implement it your way to satishfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You underestimate the complexity of DOM elements with javascript.

Using jQuery you can archive movement with:

```
$("#moving").click(function() {
    $("#exam").stop().css("marginTop", "0").animate({
      marginTop: "+=500"
        }, 1000, function() {
            display("");
        }
    );
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/margusmartsepp/dhq5p7n5/1/